# simple dash app with table with histogram that updates with selected cell

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a dash app that updates a histogram depending on what cell is selected in the 'group' column.

I can get the table to display but having trouble with the histogram.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import json

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

## create data
df_rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_rand = pd.melt(df_rand, value_vars=list('ABCD'))
df_rand_summary = df_rand.groupby('variable').describe()
df_rand_summary = df_rand_summary.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
df_rand_summary.insert(0, 'group', df_rand_summary.index)


app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    ## add table
    dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df_rand_summary.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c, } for c in df_rand_summary]
    ),

    # include histogram
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='hist'
        )
    ])

])


@app.callback(
    Output('hist', 'figure'),
    Input('table', 'active_cell'),
    State('table', 'data'))
def update_hist(active_cell, df_rand):
    # subset histogram with selected cell 
    # from 'group' column
    cell = json.dumps(active_cell, indent=2)
    row = active_cell['row']
    col = active_cell['column_id']
    value = df_rand[row][col]
    fig = px.histogram(df_rand[df_rand['variable'] == value], x='value')
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `df_rand` as a parameter to `update_hist`, you overwrite the df_rand defined outside the `update_hist`. To solve this problem, define new parameter, instead as follows:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import json

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

## create data
df_rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_rand = pd.melt(df_rand, value_vars=list('ABCD'))
df_rand_summary = df_rand.groupby('variable').describe()
df_rand_summary = df_rand_summary.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
df_rand_summary.insert(0, 'group', df_rand_summary.index)


app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    ## add table
    dash_table.DataTable(id="table",
        data=df_rand_summary.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c, } for c in df_rand_summary]
    ),

    # include histogram
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='hist'
        )
    ])

])


@app.callback(
    Output('hist', 'figure'),
    Input('table', 'active_cell'),
    State('table', 'data'), 
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_hist(active_cell, data_dict):  #<------ here we define data_dict instead of df_rand
    row = active_cell['row']
    col = active_cell['column_id']
    value = data_dict[row][col]
    fig = px.histogram(df_rand.query("variable == @value"), x='value')
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I think there's a typo? `umps(active_cell, indent=2)`